# ng-grid columnDefs showing {{ col.displayName }} and {{ grid.getCellValue }}

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, ng-grid

i have this controller:

```
$scope.allOrders = [];
OrdersFactory.query().$promise.then(function(data) {
 $scope.allOrders = data;
});
$scope.gridOptions = {
    data: 'allOrders',
    columnDefs: [
        { name:'document_no', field: 'document_no' },
        { name:'waiter_name', field: 'waiter_name' }
    ]
};
```

factory will get this data:

```
[
    {
        "id": 21, 
        "document_no": "RAC_21", 
        "waiter_name": "Name 2"
    }, 
    {
        "id": 20, 
        "document_no": "RAC_20", 
        "waiter_name": "Name"
    },
    ...
]
```

And this is result:
[image]

Why doesn't it show my data and heading for table?

Comment: The template is broken. Check the syntax in the template.

Comment: Ohh, i use `interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[')` and `$interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]')`, how can i set this in ng-grid?